# Coordinate proof of a rectangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

So I took a state test today and I'm not sure if I messed up or if I will get partial credit for my work, but here goes.
We had to prove a quadrilateral was a rectangle and I showed that all the adjacent slopes were negative reciprocal giving it all right angles. 
IS THAT ENOUGH?
Did I have to show it was a parallelogram first?

Comment: Yes, that's enough. A quadrilateral with $4$ right angles is a rectangle.

Comment: To complete BolzWeir's comment,  a quadrilateral with 3 right angles is a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.

The right angle information
shows that the alternating side
are parallel, which shows that
is is a parallelogram.

The right angle info
shows that it is a 
rectangle.